# uiwebview within uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, zooming

I am having an issue with a uiwebview within a scrollview.  In this scrollview, there is a "header" view at top and "bottomview" which is the webview.  I am loading the data into the webview using loadHTMLstring method.  What I am trying to do is that when I zoom, it should zoom in only on the bottom portion, not the top part.  This is very similiar to the native email app on the iphone.  I have been at this for 2 days now with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short : your scrollViewDelegate must implement viewForZoomingInScrollView and return the webView.

In details :

Set your scrollViewController as the delegate of the scrollView:

```
myScrollView.delegate = yourScrollViewController;
```

In YourScrollViewControllerClass.h :

```
@interface YourScrollViewControllerClass <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    [...]
}
```

In YourScrollViewControllerClass.m implement viewForZoomingInScrollView to tell which view must be zoomed when a zoom is asked :

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollViewBis {
    return yourWebView; 
}
```